# How does node-express listen both on localhost and local IP?

Tags: express, ip, localhost

I started using node express not too long and developed a simple http server using the default settings.

I have always tested it with requests to `localhost:3000` with Postman and on the browser and everything was fine.

Then I needed to move the service on the local network so that even applications not running on my machine can access it.

I got my local IP and before perform any modification I tried first with Postman using the IP address instead of localhost and also with the browser on my smartphone to check what would have happened. With my surprise it was already working on the local network, in the sense that I got a response message from the server (which might be dangerous since I did not even know).

I guess the line where you specify which address and port the server should listen on is `server.listen(port);`

If the address is not specified does it mean that it should listen both to `localhost` and local IP? Or is node-express automatically forwarding from one address to the other? Otherwise how can it work both on `localhost` and local IP?

Comment: It has noting to do with `node-express`. If not edited the host file, your `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and your local `IP` would all point to your machine

Comment: Is there a way to see which resource both of them are pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

node-express and all other web application servers listen to port, not IP address. That is, as long as port X is listened on your machine (`server.listen(port);` in node-express) and not blocked by firewall, and another host H can access your machine by IP, H can visit the web application that listen X.

> If the address is not specified does it mean that it should listen both to localhost and local IP? Or is node-express automatically forwarding from one address to the other?

"port listening" happens on transport layer, while IP address belong to network layer. When listening to the HTTP request, node-express does not care about the visitor's IP address.

> Is there a way to see which resource both of them are pointing to?

All clients visit resource in web application in the same way, it has nothing to do with client's IP, unless you manually configure it in the web application.